# How to fix “Supplied nav_menu_item value missing property” after update to Wordpress 5.0

Tags: menus, navigation

Please help. We have page on WordPress with our custom theme and minimum plugins. After update WordPress from 4.9 to 5.0.2 we have error in the admin page on Themes => Customize. Everything else is working.

I try turn off and on foreign plugins (except WP bakery). Thanks.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception:
Supplied nav_menu_item value missing property: description in /wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-nav-menu-item-setting.php:183
```

Stack trace:

```
#0 /wp-includes/class-wp-customize-nav-menus.php(692): WP_Customize_Nav_Menu_Item_Setting->__construct(Object(WP_Customize_Manager), 'nav_menu_item[7...', Array)
#1 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): WP_Customize_Nav_Menus->customize_register(Object(WP_Customize_Manager))
#2 /wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)
#3 /wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#4 /wp-includes/customize/class-wp-customize-nav-menu-item-setting.php on line 183
```

Comment: Do you have any menu items created from PHP code?

Comment: I was only able to fix this by deleting my menus and recreating them.

Answer (score 2):

I have an update on this. I discovered that if a menu item has ACF fields assigned to it and you delete a menu item, it causes this error in the Customizer. It seems as if the menu item delete functions are leaving ACF data behind in the database which is causing this. I have reached out to ACF support regarding the issue.

Comment: Did you receive a fix please?

Comment: Actually I found a fix which is different to this ACF issue. I am modifying the menu output on the front end, and although I am using code "if(!is_admin())" as I don't want it run in the admin, it is running and causes an error, I guess because customiser loads a front end view.